# Upload аудиофайла, кодированного base64

Tags: java, json, get

В спецификации API Bitrix24 есть метод telephony.externalCall.attachRecord, который позволяет загрузить в облако аудиозапись звонка.

Собственно запрос выглядит так:

```
https://test.bitrix24.ru/rest/1/tokenXXX/telephony.externalCall.attachRecord?CALL_ID=XXX&FILENAME=file.mp3&FILE_CONTENT=...<base64>...
```

Я использую метод:

```
public void externalCallAttachRecord(String call_id, File file) {
        String encoded = util.encodeToBase64(file);

        MultivaluedMap queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
        String path = properties.getBitrixId() + "/"
                + properties.getBitrixOutterWebhook() + "/telephony.externalCall.attachRecord";
        queryParams.add("CALL_ID", call_id);
        queryParams.add("FILENAME", file.getName().split(".wav")[0].concat(".mp3"));
        queryParams.add("FILE_CONTENT", encoded);
        String jsonString = request(path, queryParams);
        log.debug("externalCallAttachRecord reply is {}", jsonString);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_JAVA_ARRAY_FOR_JSON_ARRAY, true);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNRESOLVED_OBJECT_IDS, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        try {
            bitrixUploadCallEntity.setUrlEntity(objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,BitrixUploadCallEntity.class).getUrlEntity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

private String request(String path, MultivaluedMap queryParams) {
        String response = "";

        service = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig()).resource("https://"+ properties.getBitrixDomain()+"/rest/");

        try {

            log.debug("===query is {}", service.path(path).queryParams(queryParams).toString());

            ClientResponse clientResponse = service
                    .queryParams(queryParams)
                    .path(path)
//                    .post(ClientResponse.class);
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);

            if (clientResponse.getStatus() == apiState) {
                response = clientResponse.getEntity(String.class);
                log.debug("Response status is {}", clientResponse.getStatusInfo());
            } else {
                apiState = clientResponse.getStatus();
//                sendEmail(clientResponse);
                log.warn("Failed : HTTP error code : {}", clientResponse.getStatus());
                log.warn("Failed : HTTP error message : {}", clientResponse.getStatusInfo());
//                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
//                        + clientResponse.getStatus());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn(e.toString());
        }
        return response;
    }
```

У меня проблема в том, что получившийся GET запрос, слишком длинный и я получаю ошибку 414.

А можно как-то по другому передать в этом запросе тело файла?

Есть там второй способ, это сделать GET запрос, получить URL на который можно закачать файл.

Вот выдержка из спецификации:

> Методы REST-сервиса получают файлы в виде строки, закодированной в
>   base64. Также можно отправить обычный массив, первым элементом
>   которого будет имя файла, вторым - содержимое в base64.
>
> В случае полностью клиентского приложения можно либо воспользоваться
>   объектом FileReader, либо просто отдать в качестве значения поля
>   запроса ссылку на элемент формы типа "файл" ()

Я пробую на полученный URL загрузить методом POST:

```
public void uploadFile(String urlString, String fieldName, File file) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 
        try {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(urlString);
            StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{\"file\":[\""+file.getName().split(".wav")[0].concat(".mp3")+"\",\"" + encodeToBase64(file) + "\"]}");
            request.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            request.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;");
            request.setEntity(params);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn(e.getMessage());
        }
```

но получаю:

> {"error":"","error_description":"Error: required parameter file is not
>   found"}[\r][\n]"

Причем

> new
>   StringEntity("{\"file\":[\""+file.getName().split(".wav")[0].concat(".mp3")+"\",\""
>   + encodeToBase64(file) + "\"]}");

я в каких только вариациях не формировал... всегда ответ один и тот же...

Comment: А почему сразу не вызывать `telephony.externalCall.attachRecord` POST'ом?

Comment: Где у вас делается GET-запрос?

Comment: @RomanC в методе request(...) -  я его добавил в топикстарт

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev - я не против, только что это изменит?
Сначала я вызываю GET telephony.externalCall.attachRecord, в ответ получаю uploadUrl. Затем POSTом пытаюсь отправить на этот URL файл...

Comment: Столкнулся с той же проблемой с битриксом. Удалось ли Вам ее решить?

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема. 
Первое не стоит передавать в RestTemplate весь URL строкой, такой длинный URL он ломает. Перед вызовом необходимо создать URI c помощью конструктора. Во вторых если у ва массив байтов, то его необходимо сохранить во временный файл. InputStreamResource он у меня не воспринимал.

Вот мое решение, которое работает:

```
public Boolean execute(final AttachRecordRequest command) throws IOException {
    final CrmServiceEntity crmServiceEntity =
            crmServiceService.findByEnterpriseRecordId(command.getEnterpriseRecordId());

    final String clientEndpoint = crmServiceEntity.getBitrixAccessData().getClientEndpoint();
    final String accessToken = crmServiceEntity.getBitrixAccessData().getAccessToken();
    //Файл кодируется в Base64 и отправляется как текст
    //final String fileContentBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileBytes);

    final String fileName = command.getCallId() + ".mp3";
    final String attachRecord = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(clientEndpoint)
            .path("telephony.externalCall.attachRecord")
            .queryParam(AUTH_NAME, accessToken)
            .queryParam(CALL_ID_NAME, command.getCallId())
            .queryParam("FILENAME", fileName)
            // если этот параметр не указывать, то вернется uploadUrl ссылка на которую можно загрузить файл(позже)
            // .queryParam("FILE_CONTENT", fileContentBase64)
            //.queryParam("RECORD_URL", recordUrl)
            .build()
            .toString();

    log.debug(attachRecord);
    final ResponseEntity<AttachRecordResult> responseEntity = restTemplate
            .getForEntity(attachRecord, AttachRecordResult.class);
    final AttachRecordResult body = responseEntity.getBody();
    log.info("AttachRecordResult = {}", body);
    if (responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK && body != null) {

        log.debug("AttachRecord   Upload url = = {} ", body.getResult().getUploadUrl());

        final MultiValueMap<String, Object> bodyMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        // final InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(command.getMedia()));

        final File tempFile = File.createTempFile(command.getCallId(), ".mp3");

        final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        fileOutputStream.write(command.getMedia());
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();

        final FileSystemResource resourceFile = new FileSystemResource(tempFile);

        final String fieldName = StringUtils.isEmpty(body.getResult().getFieldName())
                ? "file"
                : body.getResult().getFieldName();

        bodyMap.add(fieldName, resourceFile);

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        final HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyMap, headers);

        final URI uri = URI.create(body.getResult().getUploadUrl());

        try {
            final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplateForUpload.exchange(
                    uri,
                    HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
            log.info("AttachRecord   callId = {}. Response = {}", command.getCallId(), response.getBody());
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex) {

            log.error("AttachRecord error \n"
                            + "statusCode     = {}\n"
                            + "getUploadUrl   = {}\n"
                            + "URI            = {}\n"
                            + "response body  = {}\n"
                            + "headers        = {}",
                    ex.getStatusCode(),
                    body.getResult().getUploadUrl(),
                    uri.toASCIIString(),
                    ex.getResponseBodyAsString(),
                    ex.getResponseHeaders()
            );
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            tempFile.delete();
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```